# How to authenticate to Google Compute Engine API and call a method from a client website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, google-api, google-compute-engine

These past days I've been attempting to call the method "start" from the Google Compute Engine API in order to start a virtual machine when pressing a button "start" in a website that I'm developing.

The function I'm trying to correct in Javascript is:

```
function startVM(){
    var project = 'projectName'; // placeHolder
    var zone = 'europe-southwest1-a';
    var instance = 'InstanceNumber'; // placeHolder

    var url = 'https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{' + project + '}/zones/{' + zone + '}/instances/{' + instance + '/start';
    
    const myRequest = new Request(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)'
        }
    });

    fetch(myRequest)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log(response.text());
            } else {
                throw new Error('Something went wrong on API server!');
            }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error code 401, "unauthenticated" when I submit the request.

The response from the server is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED",
        "metadatas": {
          "service": "compute.googleapis.com",
          "method": "compute.v1.InstancesService.Start"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To authenticate, I followed the first strategy from the tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/rest (the "gcloud CLI credentials" section). I converted the curl code into javascript with an online conversor. However, I believe the "gcloud" command is not being parsed correctly.

I don't have OAuth2 ID client credentials (a standard authentication method;  I have the default Compute Engine servive account, which I'm trying to find out if it's enough. If I get in the details of this account service, I saw that I have a "OAuth 2 ID client" associated.

For further information, if I execute a test request from the "Try this method" section inside: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Required 'compute.instances.start' permission for 'projects/ProjectName/zones/europe-southwest1-a/instances/InstanceNumber'",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Required 'compute.instances.start' permission for 'projects/ProjectName/zones/europe-southwest1-a/instances/InstanceNumber'",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hopefully, someone can give me a clue on how to solve this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Should I create an API key credential or an OAuth ID client credential? I'm not sure what's best or if with the service account I could handle my goal,

Comment: This line will not work in a javascript application: `'Authorization': 'Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)'`. Double check the resulting header value. The `$(command-to-execute)` is a shell script convention.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi John, understood. I managed to get through the authentication part by following correctly the documentation from Google.